# How to dispatch every previous Task that was created by particular event

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have an event in my WPF .NET 4.5 application that can be triggered up to 10 times per second, the event is computing data that is not required that often so I'm looking for a way to remove unnecessary computation stress and call the method if event wasn't triggered for 3 seconds. I thought about using `async` functionality like that:

```
private async Task DoWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    ...
}

private void Event()
{
    Task.Run(() => DoWork());
}
```

I'm not really sure about how to elegantly handle disposing of unwanted `Tasks`, ie. when user trigger the event, every task that was created by that event should be terminated and it should be as fast as possible. I've tried with `CancellationToken` but I'm not sure this is the right approach for my case

Comment: Make a bool `isRunning`. If `isRunning` is true -> return. Set the bool to true as soon as you begin the task and to false as soon as you are finished with your task.

Comment: Unfortunately I want the latest task to be executed, your proposition will block any incomming tasks if previous was not executed. I want to override previous tasks when new one arrives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was my solution based on @Fabjan answer.

```
    private static void RunSingleTask(ref CancellationTokenSource cts, int delay, Action func)
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
        }

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(delay, token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                return;
            }

            await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(func); 
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CancellationTokenSource` to let the code inside task know that it is canceled:

```
private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; } = new CancellationTokenSource ();
```

Let's change:

```
private async Task DoWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    ...
}
```

To:

```
private async Task DoWork(int timeout = 3000)
{
    await Task.Delay(timeout, CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    if(!CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Now we can cancel our task if required:

```
CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

`Task.Delay` will observe the CancellationToken and if it is in a Canceled state it will abort the task execution. Later in code we check whether we need to do anything or not.

Comment: thanks! That was the direction I needed. The only thing is that in 4.5 you cannot directly assign value to property, and `Task.Delay` will raise an exception when cancelled (TaskCanceledException)

Comment: Also we are sharing one cancellation token here so once we run `Cancel` method, the token will be always cancelled for every further events